# astravan td intermittently stalling at low revs when warm

Tags: diesel, stall, vauxhall

my 05 vauxhall astravan 1.7TD can run fine for a couple of weeks then out of the blue it stalls at low revs when warm. It will restart ok but will not tick over. Once cool it could be ok again for a while. My OBD2 code reader detects no codes. Any ideas what may be causing this will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is just a vague guess and intended as a basis for further research: Some editions of the 1.7 had issues with the pressure regulation valve on the injection pump. That could explain the described issues.